# How to classify derived words that share meaning as the same tokens?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-mining

I would like to count unrelated words in an article but I have troubles with grouping words of the same meaning derived from one another.

For instance, I would like `gasoline` and `gas` to be treated as the same token in sentences like `The price of gasoline has risen.` and `"Gas" is a colloquial form of the word gasoline in North American English. Conversely, in BE the term would be "petrol".` Therefore, if these two sentences comprised the entire article, the count for `gas` (or `gasoline`) would be 3 (`petrol` would not be counted).

I have tried using NLTK's stemmers and lemmatizers but to no avail. Most seem to reproduce `gas` as `gas` and `gasoline` as `gasolin` which is not helpful for my purposes at all. I understand that this is the usual behaviour. I have checked out a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698919/classify-words-with-the-same-meaning) that seems to be a little bit similar, however the answers there are not completely applicable to my case as I require the words to be derived from one another.

How to treat derived words of the same meaning as same tokens in order to count them together?

Comment: How do you know that "gas" is "gas[oline]," not "gas" as in "natural gas"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a two steps approach:

First, find synonyms by comparing word embeddings (only non-stopwords). This should remove similar written words, which mean something else, such as `gasoline`and `gaseous`.

Then, check if synonyms share some of their stem. Essentially `if "gas" is in "gasolin"` and the other way around. This shall suffice because you only compare your synonyms.

```
import spacy
import itertools
from nltk.stem.porter import *
threshold = 0.6

#compare the stems of the synonyms
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
def compare_stems(a, b):
  if stemmer.stem(a) in stemmer.stem(b):
    return True
  if stemmer.stem(b) in stemmer.stem(a):
    return True
  return False

candidate_synonyms = {}
#add a candidate to the candidate dictionary of sets
def add_to_synonym_dict(a,b):
  if a not in candidate_synonyms:
    if b not in candidate_synonyms:
      candidate_synonyms[a] = {a, b}
      return
    a, b = b,a
  candidate_synonyms[a].add(b)

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg') 

text = u'The price of gasoline has risen. "Gas" is a colloquial form of the word gasoline in North American English. Conversely in BE the term would be petrol. A gaseous state has nothing to do with oil.'

words = nlp(text)

#compare every word with every other word, if they are similar
for a, b in itertools.combinations(words, 2):
  #check if one of the word pairs are stopwords or punctuation
  if a.is_stop or b.is_stop or a.is_punct or b.is_punct:
    continue
  if a.similarity(b) > threshold:
    if compare_stems(a.text.lower(), b.text.lower()):
      add_to_synonym_dict(a.text.lower(), b.text.lower())



print(candidate_synonyms)
#output: {'gasoline': {'gas', 'gasoline'}}
```

Then you can count your synonym candidates based on their appearances in the text.

**Note:** I chose the threshold for synonyms with 0.6 by chance. You would probably test which threshold suits your task. Also my code is just a quick and dirty example, this could be done a lot cleaner.
`